# Need to extract and display row with a specific minimum value

Tags: python

I have the following output sample:

```
[[-5.53759409e-01 -2.68382610e-01  4.06747784e+00]
 [-1.66055379e+00 -8.08889466e-01  7.06720368e+01]
 [ 2.92172488e-01  8.17347290e-01  3.18001189e+00]
 [ 1.89072607e+00 -6.68502526e-01  9.08233869e+01]
 [-1.31451627e+00  1.61831269e+00  5.41709058e+00]
 [ 1.15886824e+00  3.31177259e-01  5.14391851e+00]
 [ 1.87270676e+00  1.24100260e+00  2.64360316e+01]
 [ 1.93323801e+00 -5.64255644e-02  7.28368451e+01]
 [ 1.33014215e+00  1.96282476e+00  2.96295301e-01]]
The minimum function value at generation 10 is [0.2962953]
```

I have concatenated two arrays - the coordinate array (elements 0 and 1) and the function values (element 2) to form the above array.

However, I would like to not only display the minimum function value e.g 0.2962953 but also the coordinates associated with it, hence the row of the above array.

Any ideas how I would approach this?

In this case, I would need the bottom row of the above array and a way to highlight the coordinates and function value.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed! Just used:  `printValues = array[np.argmin(array[:, 2]), (0,1)]`